# How can I set up multiple entry points for a svelte frontend in a symfony app?

Tags: symfony, webpack, svelte

one !! First, please forgive my english mistakes^^

So, as in the title I'm on a symfony project trying to develop a svelte frontend, and after multiple research I could not manage to find the answer. Here is my problem:

I wan't to add several entry-points in my build file like this (wepack.config.js) :

```
   /*
     * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Add 1 entry for each "page" of your app
     * (including one that's included on every page - e.g. "app")
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if your JavaScript imports CSS.
     */
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
    .addEntry('modalForm', './assets/js/modalForm.js')
```

I thought that will generate one more file in the public/build folder and get 'app.js' and 'modalForm.js'. But I'm getting 'vendors~app~modalForm.js' and 'vendors~modalForm.js' and I don't know what it is.

Actually, every thing seams to be good 'cause I got no errors, but in fact I can't see my svelte component.

Here is how I call it :

```
import ModalForm from './ModalForm.svelte';

const modalForm = new ModalForm({
    target: document.querySelectorAll("my-modal-forms"),
});
```

And in my twig template :

```
   <div class="row m-3 my-modal-forms">
    {% block javascripts %}
        {{ encore_entry_script_tags('modalForm') }}
    {% endblock %}
        <a class="btn btn-primary mr-2" href="{{ path('entity_people_new') }}"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Ajouter</a>
        <span class="not-allowed"><a class="btn text-warning mr-2" href="{{ path('import_export') }}"><i class="fas fa-file-import"></i> Import des données</a></span>
        <span class="not-allowed"><a class="btn text-warning mr-2" href="#" id="exportClick"><i class="fas fa-file-export"></i> Export des données</a></span>
    </div>
```

If you need more precisions just tell me.

Thank you all for helping, people answering on stack are really the gods are believe in.

Comment: Could you tell me how to call svelte component from symfony?

Comment: Made it with that :

https://www.garthmortensen.com/setting-up-symfony-and-svelte/

Comment: From that site: "The rest of this post assumes that you already have composer and npm (or yarn) installed." ... "For the Svelte bits let’s use Encore to configure Webpack. Encore is a great tool for using Webpack to build assets for use with Symfony." - I think that is the point.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer myself: Svelte target property does not support the querySelectorAll, or maybe I did something wrong but with a getElementById, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

querySelectorAll() returns a NodeList, Svelte's target expects a HTMLElement. querySelector() works, but getElementById() gets you there, too.